# How to get the path of thumbnail in sd card

Tags: android

I use below code to get the file pathof image in sd card.

```
File[] f = (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()).listFiles();
int i;
for(i = 0; i < f.length; i++) {
if(f[i].isFile()) {
if(isPhoto(f[i].getName())) {
Filepath.add(f[i].getAbsolutePath());
}
}
else {
//recursive
}
}
```

I want to get the path of the thumbnail of image by know original image path.
How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make your own thumbnail image:

```
byte[] imageData = null;

    try     
    {

        final int THUMBNAIL_SIZE = 64;

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);
        Bitmap imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);

        imageBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(imageBitmap, THUMBNAIL_SIZE, THUMBNAIL_SIZE, false);

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
        imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
        imageData = baos.toByteArray();

    }
    catch(Exception ex) {

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get the Uri from a file like this:

```
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File("/mnt/images/abc.jpg"));
Bitmap thumbnail = getPreview(uri);
And the following function gives you the thumbnail:

Bitmap getPreview(URI uri) {
    File image = new File(uri);

    BitmapFactory.Options bounds = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bounds.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image.getPath(), bounds);
    if ((bounds.outWidth == -1) || (bounds.outHeight == -1))
        return null;

    int originalSize = (bounds.outHeight > bounds.outWidth) ? bounds.outHeight
            : bounds.outWidth;

    BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    opts.inSampleSize = originalSize / THUMBNAIL_SIZE;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image.getPath(), opts);     
}
```